# How can I create an expendable table row with Angular Material?

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material

Using Angular Material I need my HTML table to have expandable rows like this:
[image: Expendable row]

As shown in this figure, when the content is considered too long for a cell, clicking on that (cell/row) will expand out the row. And I can expand the row in if I click on that (cell/row) again.

I tried some similar solutions [(mainly this one)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-svee9v?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) for hours, but it didn't work.

I am new to Angular and Angular Material, can someone help?
Thank you!

Comment: @Stphane There's no need to comment on what changes you've made to the question - this should be done using the edit summary text-field which is shown at the bottom of the editor.

Comment: @Edric got it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

some options:

1. your solution is not too bad, just change the content to something else
2. use Accordion Component inside each tr
3. just use Accordion Component with *ngFor, no table needed
4. for pro level make a Component which cascades the Accordion Component with relevant content [title and body] and easy use it with or without table